# update a column in mysql table with update and select statement

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to update a column in mysql(xamp) with the following code -

```
UPDATE firm SET `fk_contact_details_id` = SELECT 'id' FROM contact_details WHERE contact_details.name = firm.name
```

but I get the following error:

```
*#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your   
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT 'id' FROM contact_details WHERE   
contact_details.name = firm.name' at line 1*
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong in my statement, please?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

`SELECT 'id'`

use

`SELECT id`

Full query:

```
UPDATE firm 
    SET `fk_contact_details_id` = (
        SELECT 
            id 
        FROM 
            contact_details 
        WHERE 
            contact_details.name = firm.name
        LIMIT 1
    )
```

Comment: This query seems to work, but i get this error:#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: it means you have more rows in `contact_details` with that name ... the simple solution is to add `LIMIT 1` in the select

Comment: But it won't solve possible problem with database design. Why there are multiple firms with same names and different ids? Is it correct? Maybe Alwina should think of creating unique key constraint on field 'name'..

Comment: @cathulhu that is a very good point , i just provided a answer to his problem not a answer to his data integrity

Comment: Hi all. Thanks for your quick response.  After 'fixing' my table and running Stephan's query it worked like a bomb.